# Serial Communication, Arduino and Rpi , C library

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, c

I am currently working on a project on serial communication between RPi and Arduino. This is the code that I am using from RPi side, it's in C:

```c
int main()
{
   //-------------------------
   //----- SETUP USART 0 -----
   //-------------------------
   //At bootup, pins 8 and 10 are already set to UART0_TXD, UART0_RXD (ie the alt0 function) respectively
   int Arduino= -1;

   //OPEN THE UART
   //The flags (defined in fcntl.h):
   //   Access modes (use 1 of these):
   //       O_RDONLY - Open for reading only.
   //       O_RDWR - Open for reading and writing.
   //       O_WRONLY - Open for writing only.
   //
   //   O_NDELAY / O_NONBLOCK (same function) - Enables nonblocking mode. When set read requests on the file can return immediately with a failure status
   //                                           if there is no input immediately available (instead of blocking). Likewise, write requests can also return
   //                                           immediately with a failure status if the output can't be written immediately.
   //
   //   O_NOCTTY - When set and path identifies a terminal device, open() shall not cause the terminal device to become the controlling terminal for the process.
   Arduino = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);           //Open in non blocking read/write mode
   if (Arduino == -1)
   {
       //ERROR - CAN'T OPEN SERIAL PORT
       printf("Error - Unable to open UART.  Ensure it is not in use by another application\n");
   }

   //CONFIGURE THE UART
   //The flags (defined in /usr/include/termios.h - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/termios.h.html):
   //   Baud rate:- B1200, B2400, B4800, B9600, B19200, B38400, B57600, B115200, B230400, B460800, B500000, B576000, B921600, B1000000, B1152000, B1500000, B2000000, B2500000, B3000000, B3500000, B4000000
   //   CSIZE:- CS5, CS6, CS7, CS8
   //   CLOCAL - Ignore modem status lines
   //   CREAD - Enable receiver
   //   IGNPAR = Ignore characters with parity errors
   //   ICRNL - Map CR to NL on input (Use for ASCII comms where you want to auto correct end of line characters - don't use for bianry comms!)
   //   PARENB - Parity enable
   //   PARODD - Odd parity (else even)
   struct termios options;
   tcgetattr(Arduino, &options);
   options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;      //<Set baud rate
   options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
   options.c_oflag = 0;
   options.c_lflag = 0;
   tcflush(Arduino, TCIFLUSH);
   tcsetattr(Arduino, TCSANOW, &options);

   //----- TX BYTES -----
   unsigned char tx_buffer[20];
   unsigned char *p_tx_buffer;
   int Angle=-20;
   int Speed=100;

   int Botschaft=Fusion(Crypt(Angle),Crypt(Speed));

   p_tx_buffer = &tx_buffer[0];
   *p_tx_buffer++ = Decompositer(Botschaft,1)+'0';
   *p_tx_buffer++ = Decompositer(Botschaft,2)+'0';
   *p_tx_buffer++ = Decompositer(Botschaft,3)+'0';
   *p_tx_buffer++ = Decompositer(Botschaft,4)+'0';
   *p_tx_buffer++ = Decompositer(Botschaft,5)+'0';
   *p_tx_buffer++ = Decompositer(Botschaft,6)+'0';


   if (Arduino != -1)
   {
      int count = write(Arduino, &tx_buffer[0], (p_tx_buffer - &tx_buffer[0]));     //Filestream, bytes to write, number of bytes to write
      if (count < 0)
      {
        printf("UART TX error\n");
      }
   }

//----- CHECK FOR ANY RX BYTES -----
   if (Arduino != -1)
   {
      // Read up to 255 characters from the port if they are there
      unsigned char rx_buffer[256];
      int rx_length = read(Arduino, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);     //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
      if (rx_length < 0)
      {
        //An error occured (will occur if there are no bytes)
      }
      else if (rx_length == 0)
      {
        //No data waiting
      }
      else
      {
        //Bytes received
        rx_buffer[rx_length] = '\0';
        printf("%i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx_buffer);
      }
   }

   //----- CLOSE THE UART -----
   close(Arduino);
}

int Fusion(int Angle, int Speed)
{
   int msg;
   msg=Angle*1000+Speed;
   return msg;
}

int Decompositer(int Num,int Place)
{
   int Result[5];

   Result[0]=Num/100000;
   Result[1]=(Num-Result[0]*100000)/10000;
   Result[2]=(Num-Result[0]*100000-Result[1]*10000)/1000;
   Result[3]=(Num-Result[0]*100000-Result[1]*10000-Result[2]*1000)/100;
   Result[4]=(Num-Result[0]*100000-Result[1]*10000-Result[2]*1000-Result[3]*100)/10;
   Result[5]=(Num-Result[0]*100000-Result[1]*10000-Result[2]*1000-Result[3]*100-Result[4]*10);
   return Result[Place-1];
}

int Crypt(int Value)
{
   int result;
   result = Value + 100;
   return result;
}
```

And this is my code from the Arduino side:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial2.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    if (Serial2.available())
    {
        int inByte = Serial2.read();
        Serial.write(inByte);
    }
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        int inByte = Serial.read();
        Serial2.write(inByte);
    }
}
```

My purpose is to send a 6 digit number to my Arduino side, and be able to read them and then separate them into 2 different numbers...

The problem is I see only the first 2 digits and the rest are weird characters like `1‚þ`.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you know just what it is your Pi program is actually sending out?

Comment: I guess, Characters ? by the way I tried to set a higher baude rate and for some reason it works , I dont know why :/

Comment: Was that 115200 baud perchance?

Comment: Yes exactly! Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I have come across suituations where changing the baud rate fails miserably. Closing the port, re-opening it and setting the baud then works. It's like it only applies the baud change when the port closes. 115200 is the default baud rate the port is already on.

Comment: But do you think it might create a problem in the future?  Or should I change something in my code?

Comment: Later on I will post some other serial code that I use. I am not at my desk at the moment.

Comment: Here is how I use the serial port on Pi-like devices: https://github.com/majenkotech/SerialPort

Comment: Or you could just use one of the existing libraries on the Pi which work. Incidentally I don't know what the embedded code (with its own scroll bar) is supposed to show - it is unreadable.

Comment: This overriding problem here seems to be that you've mixed *serial communication* code with *data coding* code, without really verifying that either works by itself.  Split them apart and test your serial implementation with nice, human readable strings.  Separately test your encoding code to or from the terminal or a hex dump utility, depending on what it is you want it to be doing.